# Using resource Id's in Robotium

Tags: java, android, testing, automation, robotium

I'm using Robotium to do some automated testing on an OEM application and I am having trouble using the resource ID's. From what I understand, to use a resource id, you need to do something like this:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) solo.getView(R.id.appicon);
```

My question is: do I have to import the AUT resources folder into my test project in order to use the resource id's when I test?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use the resource id's with Robotium, you need to make sure you add the AUT to the test projects build path.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it without import the AUT resources folder like this:

```
Activity act=solo.getCurrentActivity();
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) solo.getView(act.getResources().getIdentifier("appicon", "id", act.getPackageName()));
```